# Android how can i set listview adapter when data comes in after it

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I am having a bit of an issue here with setting up a listview adapter properly. I have a listview that gets data from a AsyncTask which then get its information from a webservice in Json format and that Data becomes available only in the OnPostExecute method of the AsyncTask and I set my adapter there. The issue is that new information comes in frequently and setting the adapter up every single time leads to bad performance. How can I set up the adapter once when information comes in an AsyncTask? This is my activity...

```
public class Myprofile extends Activity {
    String URI_URL;
    Integer page;
    ProgressBar pb;
      ListView mm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myprofile);

        URI_URL = getResources().getString(R.string.PathUrl) + "/api/myprofile";
     page=0;

        new Myprofile_Async().execute();
        // Listview for adapter
       mm= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myprofiles);
        // Listview to use inside scroll event
        final ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.myprofiles);
      lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // fires off when scroll close to bottom
                if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && (lv.getLastVisiblePosition() - lv.getHeaderViewsCount() - lv.getFooterViewsCount()) >= (view.getCount() - 1)) {
                    new Myprofile_Async().execute();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }


        });

    }


   public class Myprofile_Async extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url;
        String result="";
      DataOutputStream wr;
       int id;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            id= getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
            // page Int is used to keep count of scroll events
          if(page==0)
          {page=1;}
            else {page=page+1;}
            Toast.makeText(Myprofile.this,""+page,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       // Gets data from api

            BufferedReader reader=null;
            String cert="id="+id+"&page="+page;
            try{
                url = new URL(URI_URL);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.connect();

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(cert);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();



                reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }


                result = sBuilder.toString();
                reader.close();
                conn.disconnect();
                return result;



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.err.println("cassies"+ result);

            return result;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
   // Data is returned in Json Format

                JSONObject jsonn= new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jArray = jsonn.getJSONArray("myprofile");
                JSONObject jobject=null;
                JSONArray sss= new JSONArray();
                for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    jobject= jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    jobject.getString("post");
                    jobject.getString("fullname");
                    sss.put(jobject);
                }
                jsonn.put("myprofile", sss);
                // Callout BaseAdapter to populate columns
                Myprofile_CustomView BA=new Myprofile_CustomView(jsonn,Myprofile.this);
        // Set the adapter notice the data comes from BaseAdapter BA
                mm.setAdapter(DMF);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }


    }
}
```

**Here is my updated code**

```
public class Myprofile extends Activity {
    String URI_URL;
    Integer page;
    ProgressBar pb;
      ListView mm;
    Myprofile_CustomView BA;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myprofile);

        URI_URL = getResources().getString(R.string.PathUrl) + "/api/myprofile";
     page=0;

        new Myprofile_Async().execute();
        // Listview for adapter
       mm= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myprofiles);
        mm.setAdapter(BA);
        // Listview to use inside scroll event
        /*
        final ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.myprofiles);
      lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // fires off when scroll close to bottom
                if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && (lv.getLastVisiblePosition() - lv.getHeaderViewsCount() - lv.getFooterViewsCount()) >= (view.getCount() - 1)) {
                    new Myprofile_Async().execute();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }


        });
        */

    }


   public class Myprofile_Async extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url;
        String result="";
      DataOutputStream wr;
       int id;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            id= getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
            // page Int is used to keep count of scroll events
          if(page==0)
          {page=1;}
            else {page=page+1;}
            Toast.makeText(Myprofile.this,""+page,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       // Gets data from api

            BufferedReader reader=null;
            String cert="id="+id+"&page="+page;
            try{
                url = new URL(URI_URL);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.connect();

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(cert);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();



                reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }


                result = sBuilder.toString();
                reader.close();
                conn.disconnect();
                return result;



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.err.println("cassies"+ result);

            return result;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
   // Data is returned in Json Format

                JSONObject jsonn= new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jArray = jsonn.getJSONArray("myprofile");
                JSONObject jobject=null;
                JSONArray sss= new JSONArray();
                for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    jobject= jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    jobject.getString("post");
                    jobject.getString("fullname");
                    sss.put(jobject);
                }
                System.err.println("mpee: "+ sss);
                jsonn.put("myprofile", sss);
                // Callout BaseAdapter
               // Myprofile_CustomView DMF=new Myprofile_CustomView(jsonn,Myprofile.this);
                // Set the adapter again

               BA.updateResults(jsonn,Myprofile.this);
                BA.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("mpee: " + e.toString());

            }
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Here Is My BaseAdapter

```
public class Myprofile_CustomView extends BaseAdapter {

    JSONObject names;
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater myiflater;
// Have data come in and do a toast to see changes
    public Myprofile_CustomView(JSONObject arr, Context c) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        ctx = c;
        names = arr;
        myiflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    public void updateResults(JSONObject results, Context c) {
        names=results;
        ctx=c;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(c,names+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        try {
            JSONArray jaLocalstreams = names.getJSONArray("myprofile");
            return jaLocalstreams.length();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Error: Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return names.length();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=convertView;
        MyViewHolder holder=null;

            try {
                if(row==null) {
                    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               row = li.inflate(R.layout.zmyprofile,parent,false);
                    holder=new MyViewHolder(row);
                    row.setTag(holder);
                 //   Log.d("VIX", "Creating new Row");
            }
                else
                {
                    holder=(MyViewHolder)row.getTag();
                //    Log.d("VIX", "Recycling");
                }




                JSONArray jaLocalstreams = names.getJSONArray("myprofile");
                final JSONObject jsonObject = jaLocalstreams.getJSONObject(position);
                holder.post.setText(jsonObject.getString("post"));
                holder.fullname.setText(jsonObject.getString("fullname"));


                return row;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return row;


    }

    class MyViewHolder{
        TextView post,fullname;

        MyViewHolder(View v)
        {
            post= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.post);
            fullname= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.fullname);

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapter usually takes a List of Items.

You could define an empty list of items in your `onCreate` and pass to your adapter.

Now when you get new data just update that list of items and then call this function to tell Adapter that data has changed.

```
yourAdapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I just did the following changes but now nothing is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `notifyDataSetChanged` method. In your adapter class:

```
private List myList;
...
...
public void update(List newList) {
    myList = newList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You define your adapter the first time, and in the next updates, you only call the update method with your new list.

Answer (score 0):

Sharj is correct in that you can add new data to your existing (empty) adapter. It is not necessary to call the method 
        .notifyDataSetChanged() 
because this is called internally in the adapter code.

See the  [source for ArrayAdapter](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) that shows the internal call.

Comment: Oh ok I just looked over it, I have an ArrayAdapter properly updating but since this is a JsonObject on the other side that needs updating it is not working as smoothly. I have updated my code and showed more above.